# Probability of last defective item detected at $12^{\text{th}} \text{ trial}$

Tags: probability

A lot contains 20 articles of which either $2$ or $3$ are defective and others are good. Probability that
exactly $2$ articles are defective is $0.4$. Articles are tested one by one untill all the defective items are
drawn. Final the probability that testing procedure ends at the end of $12th testing.

The solution that our teacher gave is

[image]

What my question is that isn't $C(20,11)$ incorrect because it also contains those cases where $2$ defective items are also there in 11 choosen items?

Comment: It seems to me that the testing ends at the end of the 12th test only if there are three defective items, with the third defective item appearing on the 12th test.  (If there are only two defective items you won't know that until you've tested all 20 items and not found a third defective item.)

Comment: @paw88789 But we are making 2 cases for that particular reason. Multiplication of $0.4$ makes sure that there are two defective items.

Comment: paw88789 makes a good point. If the tester doesn't know whether there are 2 or 3 defective articles, then finding 2 defective articles doesn't tell them they're done with 100% certainty. In order for this solution to work, the tester would have to know how many defective items there are before starting. And we need to be talking about the probability before the tester finds out how many defective items there are.

Answer (score 1):

${20 \choose 11}$ in the denominator is correct. $\frac{{18 \choose 10} {2 \choose 1}}{{20 \choose 11}}$ represents the probability that you draw 1 defective item in your first 11 draws.

The numerator is the number of ways you can draw 10 non-defective items and 1 defective. To get the probability, you need to divide by the number of ways you can draw 11 items, which is ${20 \choose 11}$.

If your numerator included cases where there are two defective items, then you would have a problem.